# i keep getting the good bye response no matter if i input yes or no, how would i change that so responses are correct

Tags: java, drjava

I keep getting the 'good bye' response no matter what I enter, 'yes' or 'no'. How would I change that so responses are correct.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleQuiz1 {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Are you ready to take this NBA quiz?");
    String answer = userInputScanner.nextLine();

    if(
       answer == ("yes")){
    System.out.println("Then lets get started!!!");

    } else{ 
       answer = ("no");
      System.out.println("Goodbye, come again soon!");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: try "yes".equals(answer)

Comment: Also you should put the condition on the same line of the `if`, it is strange to read it like this. Especially when your first line in the else looks like the opposite of the condition

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.equals(Object obj)` rather than `==` as `"=="` will check for reference equality whereas `.equals` compares only the content not the reference.

```
Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you ready to take this NBA quiz?");
    String answer = userInputScanner.nextLine();
    if (answer.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Then lets get started!!!");

    } else {
```

this should work fine.

Comment: This. Do your best to understand to understand this concept, as it applies to all non-primitive objects that extend `Comparable`, like `String`, and will save you many headaches in the future, especially when designing data-structures.